# How can you pass GET values to another url in php? GET value forwarding

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, cross-domain

Ok, so I'm using Jquery's AJAX function and it's having trouble passing a URL with a http address. So I'm hoping to "get" the GET values and send them to another URL — so: a local php file begin passed GET values, which in turn forwards the GET values to another url.

Maybe curl is the answer? I don't know. It's got to be a very short answer I know.

pseudo code:

```
//retrieve the GET values
$var retrieve [GET]

//passing it to another url
send get values to url ($var, url_address)
```

edit: It's a cross scripting solution for JavaScript.

Comment: May be it's only me, but I can't get the question completely. Is it JS or PHP question? What does user see while all these actions being taken?

Comment: The user doesn't see anything, it's ajax. Values are being sent with GET. However jQery.ajax doesn't like http. So I'm trying to forward those values to the service [another url] that I'm using. Makes sense?

read about the jQuery.ajax function here and how it doesn't like "http"
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: AJAX is exactly HTTP. As there is no other protocol for the web. go figure. And user have to see something. At least the same page where he stays. Well, what goes to send this request, jquery or php? If it's PHP - why all this jquery background then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/page.php?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', '&')); die();
```

If however you just want to fetch the page, use this:

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/page.php?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', '&'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: http://otherurl.com/page?var=" . $var);`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work very well. I'm gettting a 302 error in Firebug's console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude a GET param, just `unset()` before using `http_build_query()`. It might also be a good idea to include a whitelist of `$_GET` params that you'd like to pass around.

```
   header('Location: http://example.com/new?' . http_build_query($_GET));
   exit;
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). Don't forget to `exit()`.

Comment: are you sure JS object would understand such a response?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I didn't 100% understand the question, but hoped sblom was on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks Alix Axel!

```
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/page.php?'. http_build_query($_GET, '', '&'));
```

Comment: You could just use `&` to join the GET params when requesting via `file_get_contents()`. I think you only need to encode them when echoing them to the page.

Comment: Turns out it's a cross domain scripting problem that occurs with javascript. Yahoo has an article about it, they use cURL-- a little bit more complicated. http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

So this line of code is a simple php proxy.